# Java compile warning unsafe condition

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, javac

I recently started programming in java I made this code:
https://github.com/mouuff/JavaMD5cracker

The code work but I get this creppy warning:

```
C:\Users\mou\Desktop\JavaMD5cracker-master>javac icrackmd5.java
Note: .\brute.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

sounds like the compiler find this line (brute.java : l 26) unsafe or I don't know...

```
if (tries > (int)pows.get(lenght-1))
```

can someone help me with that?

Comment: Please include more of your code in your question. We need to know what `pows` is.

Comment: you may need to supply more context.

Comment: check the github link https://github.com/mouuff/JavaMD5cracker/blob/master/brute.java

Comment: declare pows like this: `Hashtable<Integer, Integer> pows = new Hashtable<>();`

Comment: So we are building a brute force MD5 cracker here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because of your hashtable declaration in **brute.java**

```
Hashtable pows = new Hashtable();
```

when the compiler executes this line

```
if (tries > (int)pows.get(lenght-1))
```

it doesnt know what the type of the element from the **pows** is.

change your hashtable declaration using generics

```
Hashtable<Integer, Integer> pows = new Hashtable<Integer,Integer>();
```

Comment: Class `Hashtable<K,V>` needs generic type argument for key and value!!

Comment: @jlordo edited it, thanks . i was thinking it was hashSet .. :P

Answer (score 1):

It's just that you are making a cast operation for `int` in another object. It's an unchecked operation since the compiler can't check if what you are returning by `pows.get(length-1)` can really be converted to an `int`.

If you trust (I mean really trust) your code and knows that a cast for `int` can always be done you can let it that way, it's just a compiler warning.

Meanwhile, give a look at the [Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) object. Maybe there's an easy and safer way to do what you are trying to accomplish.

**EDIT**

Changing this:

```
Hashtable pows = new Hashtable();
```

To:

```
Hashtable<Integer,Integer> pows = new Hashtable<Integer,Integer>();
```

Will get rid of your compiler notes.

Answer (score 1):

The class [`brute`](https://github.com/mouuff/JavaMD5cracker/blob/master/brute.java) contains this:

```
Hashtable pows = new Hashtable();
```

It's using the raw type `Hashtable`. Generics should have been used here. Also, it should have used `HashMap` instead of the legacy collection class `Hashtable`.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

The cast would then be unnecessary:

```
if (tries > pows.get(lenght-1)){
```

(Note that 'lenght' is spelled wrongly, it should have been 'length').

Besides that, the member variables should have been `private`, and the code does not conform to the de-facto coding standards that most of the world uses (class names should start with an upper-case character, variable names should not contain underscores).